# BS4 returning none from some rows

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**Summary:** BS4 isn't picking up the contents of some td elements, returning None instead of the data they contain.

**Detail:** I'm trying to scrape an HTML table using BS4 (code below). The table has multiple columns, like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><b>EICHERMOT</b></td>
    <td>28-Mar-18</td>
    <td>28,079.75</td>
    <td><span class="gr_11" style="color:#0F6C02">0.45</span></td>
    <td><span class="gr_11" style="color:#0F6C02">0.00%</span></td>
    <td>28,560.00<br>
    28,027.05</td>
    <td>28298.25</td>
    <td>49,050<br>
    1,962</td>
    <td>13,880.29</td>
    <td>197,375</td>
    <td><span class="gr_11" style="color:#0F6C02">750<br>
        0.38%</span></td>
</tr>
```

The code that i'm using to scrape the table:

```
page = open("topGainers.html")
soup =  BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
page.close()

print(soup('table')[1].findAll('tr')[i].findAll('td')[5].string)
# None
```

The problem here is that when I run this code, the `td` containing `br` tags returns `None`.
I know that this is because it has more than one child, but I'm not able to resolve the issue. Using `.text` instead of `.string` returns something like is

```
[u'28,560.00', <br/>, u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t28,027.05']
```

Expected output:

```
[u'28,560.00 28,027.05']
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: I've cleaned up your question to create a [mcve]. Your original post was too big and had lots of irrelevant code. If you don't like this edit, you can rollback [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49428951/revisions). But I suggest you keep this edit as it covers all the things you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To strip the extra whitespace from the text, you can simply use [`.get_text(' ', strip=True)`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

```
html = '''<tr>
    <td><b>EICHERMOT</b></td>
    <td>28-Mar-18</td>
    <td>28,079.75</td>
    <td><span class="gr_11" style="color:#0F6C02">0.45</span></td>
    <td><span class="gr_11" style="color:#0F6C02">0.00%</span></td>
    <td>28,560.00<br>
    28,027.05</td>
    <td>28298.25</td>
    <td>49,050<br>
    1,962</td>
    <td>13,880.29</td>
    <td>197,375</td>
    <td><span class="gr_11" style="color:#0F6C02">750<br>
        0.38%</span></td>
</tr>>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.find_all('td')[5].get_text(' ', strip=True))
# 28,560.00 28,027.05
```